# Space between rows in mdframed environment

Tags: multicol, mdframed

i'd like to reduce the space between two rows in an mdframed environment.

```
\mdfdefinestyle{round}{
innertopmargin=0pt,innerbottommargin=10pt,innerleftmargin=1pt,innerrightmargin=1pt,
middlelinewidth=3pt,innerlinewidth=0.4pt,outerlinewidth=0.4pt}

\begin{table}[tbp]
\label{tab:Liste}
\begin{mdframed}[style=round]
\caption{XXX}
\begin{multicols}{2}
{\RaggedRight
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item 1
                \item 2
                \item ...
            \end{enumerate}}
        \end{multicols}
\end{mdframed}
\end{table}
```

I already tried, `skipbelow`, `skipabove` but none of them worked.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Not sure which rows are you trying to reduce the spacing between: between the title and the first row? Or instead, are you trying to reduce the horizontal space between the vertical columns from `multicol`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space is due to `\multicolsep`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed,multicol,ragged2e}

\mdfdefinestyle{round}{
  innertopmargin=0pt,
  innerbottommargin=10pt,
  innerleftmargin=1pt,
  innerrightmargin=1pt,
  middlelinewidth=3pt,
  innerlinewidth=0.4pt,
  outerlinewidth=0.4pt
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{mdframed}[style=round]

\setlength\multicolsep{0pt} % <--- added; here it's a local setting

\caption{XXX}\label{X}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\RaggedRight
  \item some text that should go across three lines
        in order to show that they are set ragged right
  \item 2
  \item ...
  \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{mdframed}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Note that `\RaggedRight` can well go after `\begin{enumerate}`, avoiding the need of additional braces, which simplifies the input. Note also that `\label` *must* go after `\caption`.

[image]